# How to ensure bit counting method with work with both 32 and 64 bit integer inputs

Tags: c++, bit

I need to ensure by 0 bit counting method num0bits(int i) will work with both 32 and 64 bit inputs? (For example, on a machine which an int is 32 bits,num0bits(10) should return 30; if an int is 64 bits it should return 62.)

Running x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04

```
unsigned int num1bits(int i)
{
    unsigned int u = i;
    unsigned int ans = 0;
    while (u > 0) {
    ans += (u&1);
    u >>= 1;
    }
    return ans;

}

unsigned int num0bits(int i){

       if ( sizeof(i) == 4 ){
         return 32 - num1bits(i);
}else{
      return 64 - num1bits(i); 

}
}


int main(){

int input; 

while (std::cin >> input){

unsigned int onebits  = num1bits(input); 
unsigned int zerobits = num0bits(input);


std::cout << "You entered " << input << '\n'; 
std::cout << "There are " << onebits << " 1 bits set " << '\n';
std::cout << "There are " <<  zerobits << " 0 bits set " << '\n';

}
return 0;
}
```

You entered 23
There are 4 1 bits set
There are 28 0 bits set

How can I check for 64 bit inputs?

Comment: On your platform, `int` is 32 bits even in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Is your current method not working? It could use some improvement to handle also less typical sizes, but in general the idea is correct.

Comment: The method is working. I was just unsure about how I can ensure I can meet the criteria that it must work on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

Comment: add like @AProgrammer says in his comment on the current OS on which this is running,  an int is 32 bit in 64 bit mode anyway

Comment: So you could have `unsigned int num0bits(int i){ return CHAR_BIT  * sizeof(int) - num1bits(i); }`